# reinitialize or refresh the tablessorter container

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

Is there a way to refresh the tablesorter container after dynamically loading data, to remove any old or cached page data.

```
        .tablesorterPager({
            container: $("#pager"), 
            positionFixed: false,
            size:20
            })
            ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refreshing the table and data just requires triggering an update:

```
$(".tablesorter").trigger("update");
```